# Assistance in building a regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need help building a regex.

In my MVC5 view I have a text area that will contain or more groups of integers which can contain 6, 7, or 8 characters each.

In my controller I need to extract all of these numbers from the input string and put them into an array.

Examples would be:
123456 123457 123458
 or

123456 
123457
123458

or 
123456,123457, 123458

These groups may or may not have 1 or 2 leading zeroes:

00123456, 00123457 123458

This is what I ended up with:

```
    public string[] ExtractWorkOrderNumbers(string myText)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();
        var regex = new Regex(@"( |,)*(\d+)");
        var m = regex.Match(myText);

        while (m.Success)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                var wo = m.Groups[2].ToString();
                if (result.Count == 0)
                {
                    result.Add(wo);
                }
                else
                {
                    var x = (from b in result where b == wo select b).ToList().Count;
                    if (x == 0) result.Add(wo);
                }
            }
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem that you're having with the regular expressions?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: What did you tried and what problems do you have with your code? Some code snippets can be helpful

Comment: I'm not sure if a regex is the best way to meet your requirements.

Comment: A `string.Split` followed by `int.TryParse` would seem perfectly adequate in this case. Why do you think you *need* regex for this?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I'm lost when it comes to regular expressions. I've tried, but my old brain hurts when I do.

Comment: BTW, you don't need C# Regular Expressions because C# has no support for regular expressions. Fortunately, the .NET Framework _does_

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner. I'm really just looking for the best way to handle this problem, sorry for wording it poorly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumption: zero or more spaces and/or commas serve as delimiters.

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void TestMethod3()
    {
        var myText = "123456 1234567, 123458, 00123456, 01234567";
        var regex = new Regex(@"( |,)*(\d+)");
        var m = regex.Match(myText);
        var matchCount = 0;
        while (m.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match" + (++matchCount));
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
                Group g = m.Groups[i];
                Console.WriteLine("Group" + i + "='" + g + "'");
                CaptureCollection cc = g.Captures;
                for (int j = 0; j < cc.Count; j++)
                {
                    Capture c = cc[j];
                    Console.WriteLine("Capture" + j + "='" + c + "', Position=" + c.Index);
                }
            }
            m = m.NextMatch();
        }
    }
```

Output:
(For each match, all Group2's are your matches, Group1 is the delimiter)

```
Match1
Group1=''
Group2='123456'
Capture0='123456', Position=0
Match2
Group1=' '
Capture0=' ', Position=6
Group2='1234567'
Capture0='1234567', Position=7
Match3
Group1=' '
Capture0=',', Position=14
Capture1=' ', Position=15
Group2='123458'
Capture0='123458', Position=16
Match4
Group1=' '
Capture0=',', Position=22
Capture1=' ', Position=23
Group2='00123456'
Capture0='00123456', Position=24
Match5
Group1=' '
Capture0=',', Position=32
Capture1=' ', Position=33
Group2='01234567'
Capture0='01234567', Position=34
```

Comment: Then do whatever you would like with the captured groups.  TryParse them to ints, pad them with leading zeros, whatever.

Answer (score 0):

By using the [named capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html) feature of regular expressions (Regex), we can extract the data from matching patterns. In your case, we can extract the non-zero integer portion of the text string:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// A pattern consisting of at most two leading zeros followed by 6 to 8 non-zero digits.
var regex = new Regex(@"^[0]{0,2}(?<Value>[1-9]{6,8})$");

var firstString = "123456";
var secondString = "01234567";
var thirdString = "0012345678";

var firstMatch = regex.Match(firstString);
var secondMatch = regex.Match(secondString);
var thirdMatch = regex.Match(thirdString);

int firstValue = 0;
int secondValue = 0;
int thirdValue = 0;

if (firstMatch.Success)
  int.TryParse(firstMatch.Groups["Value"].Value, out firstValue);

if (secondMatch.Success)
  int.TryParse(secondMatch.Groups["Value"].Value, out secondValue);

if (thirdMatch.Success)
  int.TryParse(thirdMatch.Groups["Value"].Value, out thirdValue);

Console.WriteLine("First Value  = {0}", firstValue);
Console.WriteLine("Second Value = {0}", secondValue);
Console.WriteLine("Third Value  = {0}", thirdValue);
```

Output:

```
First Value  = 123456
Second Value = 1234567
Third Value  = 12345678
```

Comment: This works if the string it's checking is "123456", but not if the string is "123456 123456". Also, the results will still be strings, not integers. It just so happens that the string is made up entirely of integers. These are stored in a legacy database as strings. At a further point in the code I have to add the leading zeroes if the user does not put them in (which I know how to do).

Comment: Ah, do you need to split up the groups into individual integer strings? For example "123456 01234567" -> "123456" , "01234567" or is it simply for validation of each "line" ?

Comment: I will use each integer string in a db query 'where' clause similar to :
select x, y, z 
from myTable 
where someField='00123456' or someField = '00123457' or someField = '00123458'